# Elements can't float below the previous row's too tall first element

Tags: css, css-float

I have a list of floated elements with a width of about 33%, so 3 elements per line. Their height vary. Also, I am using a Javascript sorting plugin and cannot use the CSS property.

Problem: if the first element of a given row is taller than the other ones, then the first element of the next row cannot float below it. How to fix that?

[image]

CSS:

```
.resource_item {
    float: left;
    width: 31%; 
    margin-bottom: 30px;    
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
```

PHP:

```
while ...

    ?>
    <div class='resource_item'>
        Content
    </div>
    <?php

endwhile;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can't use "clear" because I'm using a Javascript sorting plugin that can re-organize all elements (by making some invisible)

Comment: @Paulie_D: it's not a duplicate of the question you mentioned, in which a masonry type of layout is sought. In that question, I want what the questioner has in the first place!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a comment pointed out (the person removed it for some reason) the problem is solved by setting the elements as `display: inline-block` instead of floating them.